# Remove volumeMount on pvc delete

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-python-client

My usecase is as follows:
I have a deployment for a multi-tenant service. This deployment has many mountVolumes associated with it, which are pvcs specific to a tenant. When I delete a tenant, I want to delete the associated pvc as well. And in turn also delete it from the deployment.

## I tried using strategic-merge for this:

x.yaml - this contains the patch yaml:

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      volumes:
      - $patch: delete
        name: "tenant-helloworld"
```

========================
invoking method:

```
name = 'test-ms'
with open('resources/x.yaml') as filein:
x_yaml = yaml.load(filein)
pprint(x_yaml)
api_response=client.ExtensionsV1beta1Api(). patch_namespaced_deployment(name=name,namespace=namespace,body=x_yaml,
```

pretty=True)

========================
exception on invoking patch_namespaced_deployments:

`"status": "Failure",
"message": "Deployment.apps \"test-ms\" is invalid: spec.template.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[9].name: Not found: \"tenant-helloworld\"",
  "reason": "Invalid",
  "details": {
    "name": "test-ms",
    "group": "apps",
    "kind": "Deployment",
    "causes": [
      {
        "reason": "FieldValueNotFound",
        "message": "Not found: \"tenant-helloworld\"",
        "field": "spec.template.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[9].name"
      }
    ]
  },
  "code": 422
}`

The field is present at volumeMount[9]. Any pointers on where am I going wrong.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, I do not intend to offend, but your question appears to be a bit off topic here at StackOverflow. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic to get an idea of what kind of problems are discussed here.

Comment: @Twonky Thanks for helping a noob :) I hope this question fits SO now.

Comment: You are trying to "patch" a deployment. This error may be caused becasue the Deployment does not exist, are you sure the namespace name and deployment match? Also, can you please confirm that the x.yaml actualy is patching a DEPLOYMENT and not a TEMPLATE?

Comment: Yep the deployment is existing. And it is not patching a template. Seems like the format was an issue for the patch yaml. I corrected the format, and it seems to be working now.

Comment: Since your issue seems to be solved, can you please mark this question as closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to formatting of yaml. Hence closing the issue.